# Less than actual data in html table

Tags: jsoup

I'm doing

```
Element tbody = doc.select("td#tab table tbody").first();
System.out.println(tbody.childNodeSize());
```

on the following url.

http://164.100.181.140/fcs/Helpline/NFSA/ReportRegidWise.aspx?val=NSMxODcjUiMwMDEzNzMjMDM3OTg0IzEwMDEwMDMwMDAxMiNCUEwjMDkxODcwMDk0NjE4NDI5MQ%3d%3d

But only getting back **5 tr elements**

Later I tried to see what jsoup is returning it shows just 5 tr elements.

```
System.out.println(tbody.html());
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('td#tab table tbody').childNodes.length
```

shows 623 records.

Is there something wrong with Jsoup parser or I'm making some mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document starts with a lot of encoded data. Jsoup truncates the size after 1M I think. If you want to get the whole document you can configure this like so:

```
String url = "http://164.100.181.140/fcs/Helpline/NFSA/ReportRegidWise.aspx?val=NSMxODcjUiMwMDEzNzMjMDM3OTg0IzEwMDEwMDMwMDAxMiNCUEwjMDkxODcwMDk0NjE4NDI5MQ%3d%3d";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .timeout(10000)
                .maxBodySize(0)  //setting to 0 turns size checking off
                .get();

Element tbodyEl = doc.select("td#tab table tbody").first();
System.out.println(tbodyEl);
```

This takes a bit longer, but you get all info.