# Web scraping with jsoup is returning only part of the table

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am new at coding.
I'm trying to webscrape a table with a list of funds from a broker's website. The code is working fine but ut is returning only part of the list (a bit more then the first half of the list), and I can't find out why

I've already checked the html strucutre and the tags and everything seems to be right...

```
int count = 0;
String URL = "https://institucional.xpi.com.br/investimentos/fundos-de-investimento/lista-de-fundos-de-investimento.aspx";

try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();
            
for (Element table: doc.select("#tableTodos tr")) {
    Elements tds = table.getElementsByTag("td");
    if (tds.size() > 0) {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count + " - " + tds.get(2).text());
}
```

This is the final part of the return

```
138 - Kapitalo Kappa FIN FIC FIM
139 - Kapitalo Tarkus FIC FIA
140 - Kinea Atlas II FIM
141 - Kinea Chronos FIM
142 - Kinea RF Absoluto FI LP
143 - Leblon Ações FIC FIA
144 - Legacy Capital Advisory FIC FIM
145 - Legg Mason Clearbridge US Large Cap Growth FIA IE
146 - Legg Mason Martin Currie European Absolute Alpha FIM IE
147 - Mauá Capital Ações FIC FIA
```

It goes only to 147, the table at the website has more than 300 rows...

Comment: did you check the HTML content when downloading it via `curl` or something? Is the whole table in the output then?

Comment: `td` denotes columns, rows are specified by `tr` in an HTML table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Less than actual data in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207012/less-than-actual-data-in-html-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should search the elements in the table by "tr" tag and not td. It will give you all the rows in the table. then, in each row, search for the td and print it's text.

**EDIT 1:**

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    chromeDriver.get("https://institucional.xpi.com.br/investimentos/fundos-de-investimento/lista-de-fundos-de-investimento.aspx");
    List<WebElement> elements = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tableTodos\"]")).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    System.out.println(elements.get(200).getText());
```

**EDIT 2:**

Add maxBodySize yo your get call:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Comment: I changed the cod to get the tag "tr" and was able to select witch row I want using this: System.out.println(row.getElementsByTag("tr").get(100).text()); but when I try using get(200) it returns this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 200, Size: 148 - when I see the table at the website, it has more rows, could it be split in more then 1 table?

Comment: you are correct. When loading the page with Jsoup, only 148 table rows are there in the HTML. This is because there is a dynamic javascript code running in the browser context. Since Jsoup is just HTML parser and not a browser, there is no much thing to do in this case (except for maybe trying to run the JS manually). I would recommend using Selenium WebDriver for that, added a code sample in the answer.

Comment: @AdiOhana I do not think selenium is needed here. The content is not loaded via AJAX. It is just more than 1MB that is loaded in the call.

Comment: @luksch yes, I don't see any ajax requests, and, more interesting, CURL command return the "full" html with all table rows. there is definitely a bug in Jsoup. I will continue to investigate. Still, Selenium is a good option here.

Comment: no bug in JSoup. Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207012/less-than-actual-data-in-html-table. 
There is a 1MB limit with the connect method, but it can be configured.

Comment: works perfectly. wonder why it is cutting specifically form the table..

Comment: Adi Ohana, I used your code Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(0).maxBodySize(0).get() and now it returns all the rows thanks!!!!